# Why is the "uniqueness: true" validation not working in my test (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, unique, minitest

In my Rails app, I am trying to save MAC addresses for devices belonging to different users. Each MAC address must be unique, so I included the uniqueness validation.
The validation itself seems to be working, since duplicate records were rejected when I tried using the Rails Console (`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`). However, my test to check that only unique records can be saved is failing.

So my questions are:

1. Why is my test failing and how can I fix it?
2. I read elsewhere that the uniqueness validation alone is not a reliable way to assure uniqueness. Should I use other methods, such as `before_save` callbacks?

This is the error message I'm getting for the test:

`Expected #<MacAddress id: nil, user_id: nil, address: "MACADD123", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> to be nil or false`

Setup in my model files:

```rb
# app/models/mac_address.rb

class MacAddress < ApplicationRecord
  validates :address, uniqueness: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```rb
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :mac_addresses, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Test to check for uniqueness:

```rb
class MacAddressTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
test 'mac address must be unique' do
    new_mac = 'MACADD123'
    assert MacAddress.create(user: User.first, address: new_mac)
    assert MacAddress.all.pluck(:address).include?(new_mac)

    # The 'assert_not' below is failing.
    assert_not MacAddress.create(user: User.second, address: new_mac)
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Regarding 2) you should add a uniqueness constraint to the database in addition to your validation.

Comment: To trigger the validation you could simply `assert MacAddress.new(...).invalid?`. If you want to ensure that no additional records were created, it might be better to check that `MacAddress.count` remains unchanged.

Comment: @Stefan I added the uniqueness constraint to the DB when I created the migration. Also noted on your other points. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the documentation on `create`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create):

Notice there's no `id` for that record. It hasn't been persisted. Check for errors with `.errors.full_messages` to see the uniqueness validation failure.

> The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

You should assert that it's saved, like:

```
mac_address = MacAddress.create(...)
assert !mac_address.new_record?
```

Where that tells you if it's been saved or not. Alternatively you can use `create!` which will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` if it failed.

Comment: Thank you! As you pointed out, the error was because the `create` method returned the object regardless of whether it was actually saved to the DB. Solved by instead asserting whether it's saved or not.

Comment: As a note, the [`persisted?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F) method tells you if the model has been saved. In practice this is the opposite of `new_record?` but might make your tests more readable.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference and for anyone viewing this question - I rewrote my test with `save` instead of `create` like below:

```rb
test 'mac address must be unique' do
    test_address = 'MACADD123'
    original_mac = MacAddress.new(user: User.first, address: test_address)
    duplicate_mac = MacAddress.new(user: User.second, address: test_address)

    assert original_mac.save
    assert MacAddress.pluck(:address).include?(test_address)
    assert_not duplicate_mac.save
    duplicate_mac.errors.messages[:address].include?('has already been taken')
end
```

Comment: You can also assert that a duplication message was added as an error, not that it wasn't saved for what could be unrelated reasons.